# Cleaning up an object only if an exception is raised

Tags: python, exception, try-catch-finally

I need to have a file deleted if not all the operations that must be done on it were successful (that is, if an exception is raised). It could have been as simple as using *except:*, deleting the file and then re-raising the exception, but in that case the original exception would be lost if the file cannot be deleted in the *except* clause for whatever arcane reason.

The best that I have been able to come up with is this:

```
try:
    file_path = "whatever.jpg"
    # do stuff with file
except:
    exception_raised = True
    raise
finally:
    try:
        if exception_raised:
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except:
        pass

return file_path   # everything OK
```

Does anybody know of a better, more Pythonic approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to simply store the exception if you don't want to lose it:

Python 3.x version:

```
try:
    file_path = "whatever.jpg"
    # do stuff with file
except BaseException as e:
    try:
        os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
```

The Python 2.x version is slightly more complex since you need to store the complete exception information manually (otherwise you'd lose the traceback):

```
try:
    file_path = "whatever.jpg"
    # do stuff with file
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    raise e[0], e[1], e[2]
```

**Edit**: Only catch subclasses of `Exception` in the inner `try` block, since you don't want do catch `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt` here.  Also report any excpetion that occurred during unlinking instead of just dropping it.

Comment: Of course, this will not work for exceptions that are not derived from `BaseException`.

Comment: @Mankarse: In Python 3, all exceptions must be derived from BaseException.  In Python 2, an exception class must either be derived from `BaseExcpetion` or be an old-style class.  Old-style classes are phasing out for ten years now, so the above code should be pretty safe if you aren't using *very* old libraries using strange exception classes.

Comment: @Mankarse: There was a different problem with the code for Python 2.x -- the traceback of the exception was lost.  Fixing this problem also removed the (minor) restriction to `BaseException`.

Comment: That's what I had overlooked and precisely what I was looking for: sys.exc_info(). Perfect. Thanks, Sven.